# UINavigationBar with dynamically drawn background

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I know how to subclass the UINavigationBar and override the drawRect: method and use the graphics context to draw stuff.  However it seems like it is only called once.

I want to be able to draw a different background with a click of a button.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup background colour with following function, that generates random colour:

```
- (UIColor*) randomColor {

    CGFloat r = (float)(arc4random() %256) / 255;
    CGFloat g = (float)(arc4random() %256) / 255;
    CGFloat b = (float)(arc4random() %256) / 255;

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:0.7f];

}
```

Usage:

```
UIColor * color = [self randomColor];
```